# Creating an Interface by adding elements using arraylist

Tags: java

I have a problem solving for adding a group of element in my collection using arraylist. I have a Class Student that has 3 variables. And Interface that has add, delete, and get student but in my testing i couldn't show different results.

```
String studId = "";
String firstName = "";
String lastName = "";
int number = 0;
int index = 0;
StudentServiceImpl studServImpl = new StudentServiceImpl();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Student student = new Student();
    do {
        System.out.println("1.Add Student:");
        System.out.println("2.Delete Student:");
        System.out.println("3.Display Students:");
        System.out.println("4.Exit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Select number: ");
        System.out.println();
        number = scan.nextInt();
        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter Student No.");
            studId = scan.next();
            student.setStudId(studId);
            System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
            firstName = scan.next();
            student.setFirstName(firstName);
            System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");
            lastName = scan.next();
            student.setLastName(lastName);
            studServImpl.add(student);
        } else if (number == 2) {
            // TODO:
        } else if (number == 3) {
            List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            studentList = studServImpl.getStudent();
            System.out.println("\nThe size of List: " + studentList.size());
            for (Student studentRec : studentList) {
                System.out.println("Student ID: " + studentRec.getStudId());
                System.out.println("First Name: " + studentRec.getFirstName());
                System.out.println("Last Name: " + studentRec.getFirstName() + "\n");
            }
        } else if (number == 4) {
            System.out.println("Thank you, Good Bye!");
        }
    } while (number != 0);
```

Its output is

entering 1 for add

I enter the values that is ask

and then repeat it now I have a size of 2 in my List

but it display same output even though I enter different values like `{123,Jun,Jack},{135,Jon,Bill}:`

```
results:

Student ID: 123
FirstName: Jun
LastName: Jack

Student ID: 123
FirstName: Jun
LastName: Jack
```

HELP!!

Comment: can you please format the code....

Comment: Does your code compiles? You are calling student.setFirstName but student is an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You want us to spend our time to help you doing your homework. So you please spend the 5 minutes it takes to put up a **proper** [mcve] and properly indented code - instead of dropping such a mess on us!

Comment: I didn't see increament of `index`...

Comment: You only create one Student as a field of the Class. Add the line `student =  new Student();` inside your `if(number==1)` block to create a new student when you...well, want to create a new student.

Comment: You created only one student object and you are continuously updating that single instance

Comment: Sorry im trying to create an Array of object so i dont type 100 student object but it's hard for me. How can I create new object for student that has 3 variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String studId = "";
String firstName ="";
String lastName ="";
int number =0;
int index = 0;
StudentServiceImpl studServImpl = new StudentServiceImpl();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

do{

System.out.println("1.Add Student:");
System.out.println("2.Delete Student:");
System.out.println("3.Display Students:");
System.out.println("4.Exit");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Select number: ");
System.out.println();
number=scan.nextInt();

if(number==1){
    Student student =  new Student();
    System.out.println("Enter Student No.");
    studId = scan.next();
    student.setStudId(studId);

    System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
    firstName = scan.next();
    student.setFirstName(firstName);

    System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");
    lastName = scan.next();
    student.setLastName(lastName);

    studServImpl.add(student);

}


    else if(number ==2){



    }

    else if (number == 3){

    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    studentList = studServImpl.getStudent();

    System.out.println("\nThe size of List: "+studentList.size());



    for (Student studentRec : studentList) {
        System.out.println("Student ID: "+ studentRec.getStudId());
        System.out.println("First Name: "+ studentRec.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name: "+ studentRec.getLastName()+"\n");


    }

    }

    else if(number == 4){

        System.out.println("Thank you, Good Bye!");
    }



    }


    while(number!=0);

}
```

Your code could have been this, note that the only change I made is making the student object a local variable inside the block where you do the input.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiated `student` outside of your loop, and added it multiple times with menu item `1`.

Should move the instantiation inside the loop...